# Makefile with shell command grep

Tags: makefile, grep, conditional-statements

I am having an issue i have beating my head in with all morning. I am a newbie to modifying makefiles so i have come across an issue i do not know how to solve. I am trying to search through a directory for any files ending in 'Findings.txt' that has the string 'No Findings!' contained inside it. For some reason i cannot get my conditional statement to work properly. I am assuming it might have to do with the wildcard character but everything i have tried has not worked including the  wilcard function. My only othera thought is the shell might have an issue with a variable in the path.

```
GREP_FINDINGS := $(shell grep 'No Findings'  $(C_DIR)/*Findings.txt)
```

I want to conditionalize the output of the grep result but i am doing something wrong.

```
ifeq ($(GREP_FINDINGS), )
    @echo "Nothing was found for current build"    
else  
    @echo "***Found string in Findings.txt***"
endif
```

Comment: What version of Make are you using? (Try `make -v` if you're not sure.) Does `GREP_FINDINGS` contain what you think it should? How does your conditional statement go wrong? Does it take the first branch when there's something in `GREP_FINDINGS`, or does it take the second when there should be nothing?

Comment: I am using GNU make 3.8 with tcsh in unix. In its current form it does not trigger the first branch and always takes the second. I only use GREP_FINDINGS for this conditional so I assume it contains what I want as i tested the command in the console beforehand. I am still learning as i go. I always assumed grep returned a zero output if it found the string and nonzero elsewise. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That doesn't look like valid Make code (e.g. the parentheses aren't balanced); could you cut and paste the actual code?

Answer (score 3):

Makefiles are generally case sensitive, so you need to use `ifeq` and `else`, the following works here with GNU Make:

```
ifeq ($(GREP_FINDINGS), )
  @echo true
else
  @echo false
endif
```

You might also want to check [this](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/make/make_7.html) out.

Comment: I just updated with my actual code because before I was typing on my cell phone from memory. I am actually using the conditionals already and it still skips the first branch..

Comment: @MattCzarniak, try cutting and pasting the `ifeq` line from this answer-- I think you've omitted a space.

Comment: ok. I couldn't believe I didn't notice the space. Interesting enough I added that space in and it activated the first branch of the conditional, which is what I want to happen. However, I switched the string I used to grep to 'blah', which is not contained in any of my Findings files, and it returns the first branch also.. Is there a chance that a syntax error elsewhere in the Makefile could cause it to behave funny? Thanks for everyone's help

Comment: In that case you could use `find`, something like: `find . -name '*Findings.txt' | xargs grep 'No Findings'` should work.

Comment: it works in the console like my grep command did but it still isn't correctly working when I put a string like 'blah' in it. I had to add a relative path to the findings file directory and I am wondering if I screwed it up. I also tried adding a second $ to my $(C_DIR) and changing to double quotes but nothing affected the outcome. Thanks.. ***find . -name '$(C_DIR)/*Findings.txt' | xargs grep 'No Findings'***

Comment: Did you try `ifeq ($(strip $(GREP_FINDINGS)),)`? See also http://sunsite.ualberta.ca/Documentation/Gnu/make-3.79/html_chapter/make_7.html#SEC73 and see if it has other useful hints.

Comment: thanks guys. turns out everyone was right.. I have a seperate issue